# Remove Word formatting before input mysql, for a JSON output

Tags: php, mysql, json

after spending 2 hours on a stupid bug i realized that it was caused by a user who input a text containing indent text, bullets etc (i'm talking about a classifieds website)
so as the output is JSON i was receiving an error..

i know this is the holy grail of the quetions but what a simple, quick&dirty solution to
 clean the output form extra spece,tab space etc, so JSON is valid?

(of course would be better to clean the input first but that's another question)

Comment: How/where are you generating this json? json_encode() in PHP would take care of any wonky characters that'd throw off the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if what you are looking for is something like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)?

You can try the [demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php).

There should be a good website for validating JSON [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Sorry I am not native English.

- EDIT: I just re-read you question, this was not really what you where looking for I think, but I'll leave it here just in case anyway :).

Comment: great! actually thank to you answer I found out KSES, used by wordpress..cool

Answer (score 1):

What about `json_encode()`?

http://php.net/json_encode

*Which btw is already mentioned by `Marc B` in a comment to the question. I didn't see that until now -- I'm sorry. (added)*

Comment: I'd like to use json_encode but what if I need to create a custom JSON with different name than those taken from the mysql table name?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to handle this is to do it on form entry on the client side.  Basically, by the time it gets to the server, very difficult to 'scrub' MS special characters out.  Basically, a simple Javascript function tied to field change on a form element that converts any bogus characters to their UTF-8 friendly equivalent is the way to go.  Check out this link: http://www.kevinkorb.com/post/37